# Customize data labels in pandas pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I am trying to create a python pie chart from a dataframe with customized data labels.
The dataframe that I am working off of contains percentages the correspond to each of the pie chart sections. I would like to display those percentages as data labels rather than the percent values of the totals of the whole. Excel does allow me to do that. How can I do it in Python?

```
chart = pd.DataFrame({"market_value": [229500,261377,341155], 'exposure':[.007648,.008712,.011372]}, index = ["Large", "Mid", "Small"])  
chart.plot.pie(title="Exposure by Market Cap", y="market value", figsize(8,8))
```

Excel Pie Chart
[image: Excel pie chart]

Python Pie Chart
[image: Python pie chart]

Comment: Some code to be able to generate that pie chart as well as the corresponding labels would be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html

Comment: @HenryEcker 
`chart = pd.DataFrame({"market_value": [229500,261377,341155], 'exposure':[.007648,.008712,.011372]}, index = ["Large", "Mid", "Small"])

chart.plot.pie(title="Exposure by Market Cap", y="market value", figsize(8,8))`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @ifly6's comment in the original question somewhat: `DataFrame.plot.pie()` passes the `autopct` parameter down to `matplotlib`, so adding that parameter will accomplish what you want here:

```
chart = pd.DataFrame({"market_value": [229500,261377,341155], 'exposure':[.007648,.008712,.011372]}, index = ["Large", "Mid", "Small"])  
chart.plot.pie(
  title="Exposure by Market Cap", 
  y="market value", 
  autopct="%.2f%%",
  figsize(8,8)
)
```

The example in [matplotlib's docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html) has a lot of extra functionality for styling the labels, but if all you need is labels, `autopct` will get you there.